# How to set transform origin for QPainter In Qt

Tags: qt, rotation, pyqt, transform, qpainter

I am using **PyQt** and more accurate `QPainter` for drawing a line. I need to rotate this line around an origin point (like clock handles), but setting it is not possible, I think!
I found `setTransformOriginPoint` but it doesn't work for `QPainter` object. Setting origin point is not possible for `QTransform` and `rotate` that could affect `QPainter` object.

Also I tried rotating the line manually, using rotation equation and ..., this is the code:

```
def rotateLine(x, y, d):
    d = math.radians(d)
    x2 = x * math.cos(d) - y * math.sin(d)
    y2 = x * math.sin(d) + y * math.cos(d)
    return x2, y2
des = QPoint(400, 0)
for k in range(0, 10):
    paint.drawLine(center, des)
    newLine = rotateLine(des.x(), des.y(), 45)
    des = QPoint(newLine[0], newLine[1])
    logging.warning(des)
```

But it doesn't work correctly!
What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one typical solution is to translate, rotate, and then draw.  Here's a sample in C++ that will draw lines like hands on a clock with center at (50, 50) and extending from radius=0 to radius=400, with 45° between them.

```
QPainter painter(this);
painter.save();
painter.translate(50, 50);  // Center
for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
    painter.drawLine(0, 0, 400, 0);
    painter.rotate(45);     // Degrees
}
painter.restore();
```

Side note: Your rotateLine() function is correct for rotating the given point about the origin but it looks like you wanted it to rotate it about `center`.  You could also get the desired effect by changing your call to `drawLine` to `paint.drawLine(center, center + des)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! the point was transforming the `Qpainter` object, not transforming with `QTransform`.